# Swift PDF create Rectangle?

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to create an rectangle on an PDF File, but i dont how to do that. Its simple to create some text or images, but i would like to add some shapes like rectangles and circles.

Is the *UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo* the same as the CGContext?

At the moment i am using this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(pdfFileName, CGRectZero, nil);
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, 612, 792), nil);

// add some text
let mainTitle = "..."
mainTitle.drawInRect(CGRectMake(30, 110, 552, 40), withAttributes: textAttributesBoldLargeHeader)
```

But how to add a custom rectangle?

Comment: Draw your view and save it as pdf

Comment: ? and how? i cannot create a simple UIView? Or what do you mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just get the PDF drawing context with `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()`
and draw anything to it. Simple example:

```
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(pdfFileName, CGRectZero, nil);
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, 612, 792), nil);

let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, UIColor.blueColor().CGColor)
let rect = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 100, height: 200)
CGContextFillRect(context, rect)

UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
```

Comment: Thank your for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can also extend UIView to render the current context and save the data as pdf file:

**Swift 3 or later**

```
extension UIView {
    var pdfData: Data {
        let result = NSMutableData()
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(result, frame, nil)
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return result as Data }
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()
        layer.render(in: context)
        UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
        return result as Data
    }
}
```

Testing:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let rectangle = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 30, y: 110, width: 350, height: 40))
    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        shapeLayer.path = rectangle.cgPath
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        do {
            try view.pdfData.write(to: FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!.appendingPathComponent("view.pdf"), options: .atomic)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```