# How to save a picture of an entire view Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm saving a view using .writetofile . I need to save the full view not just a screenshot size on every device . The problem it's only taking a screenshot which size varies from every device. I need it to save the same size on every device. How can I save the whole view at the same size in every device.

How it saves on iPad : http://postimg.org/image/s25l0q6qh/
How it saves on iPhone4s : http://postimg.org/image/jy6nngz2x/

The pdfData is a view extension that I got from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35094275/2303865)

How can I save the hole view at a certain size on every device?

Here's my code for saving :

```
view.pdfData.writeToURL(NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first!.URLByAppendingPathComponent("test.pdf"), atomically: true) 
view.pdfData.writeToFile("test.pdf", atomically: false)
print(NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first!.path!)
```

Comment: You need to pass the size to take the snapshot of your desired size.

Comment: So, how are you creating the pdf data?

Comment: Like this @Sulthan :

Comment: extension UIView {
    var pdfData: NSData {
        let result = NSMutableData()
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(result, frame, nil)
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return result }
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()
        layer.renderInContext(context)
        UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
        return result
    }
}

Comment: How should I do this @TejaNandamuri?

Comment: @NiallKehoe create a custom view device independent with the correct size, draw your elements on it and render it instead of the regular view

Comment: How should I create the custom view device independently?

Comment: @NiallKehoe just define your "page" view frame size the same size for all. It does not have to be proportional to all screens and or fit on them. It needs to be proportional to your pdf  page size

Comment: Like this?  http://postimg.org/image/6a7r5ipt9/

Comment: Thanks @LeoDabus that works, please fill that in as the answer. Big help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just define your "page" view frame size the same size for all. It does not have to be proportional to all screens and or fit on them. It needs to be proportional to your pdf page size. Draw your elements on it and render it instead of the regular view.