# Swift: Getting better quality image when rendering PDF

Tags: swift, pdf, render

I am rendering a PDF from several storyboard views and everything is working great...with one exception. A large, circular image is getting a narrow, dark border even though the original has none. It's a very light image so I get why it might not be rendered perfectly. I found some older solutions but nothing that has helped so far. Thanks!

[image]

```
private func toPDF(views: [UIView]) {
        let pageWidth = 612
        let pageHeight = 792         
        let pdfData = NSMutableData()

        UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: pageWidth, height: pageHeight), nil)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        for view in views {
            UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()
            view.layer.render(in: context!)
        }
}
```

Comment: have you tried multiplying the page width and height by the screen scale?

Comment: I did see that solution in an older post, though I admit that it didn't make sense to me. I ended up with a PDF that still had the border and was only a fraction of the desired size. To get the screen scale I divided 300 by 72. Then I multiplied the page width and height by the result.

Comment: I meant pixels not inches. do `width * UIScreen.main.scale`. Btw you should post how did you come up with the pageWidth value.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35094275/2303865

Comment: The page width and height are US Letter - 612 x 792 points. I'll play around with the scale but I don't understand what I'm trying to accomplish. If I scale the document, my PDF will no longer be the correct size...right?

Comment: I don't know what is the size of your original view. I can only guess you are rendering a small view in a larger canvas. Try creating your views at the size you will render it 612 x 792 . Your view that will be rendered doesn't need to be the same size of your device screen.

Comment: I think you will have a better control over it if you use PDFKit https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfpage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple enough. I was using a PNG with a transparent background which caused the border in the PDF as shown below. When I changed the PNG to a solid white background, the border disappeared.

[image]

Comment: Looks  like a [pre-multiplied alpha vs. straight alpha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing#Description) issue.